# Update Eclipse variable via External Tool

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

My apologies if this is well known, or posted else where.  I have not found what i am looking for.

I am trying to set the value of a global "workspace" level variable in eclipse using a external tool.  By workspace level, I mean that it is not specific to a build, debug, or run configuration.

Is this possible?  If not, is there a work around that you can suggest?  I have tried making my external tool set a windows environment variable, but eclipse did not recognized said environment variable until i restarted it.

On a side note, I found the following.
[Set Environment Variable At Eclipse workspace level for all launchers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20011399/set-environment-variable-at-eclipse-workspace-level-for-all-launchers)

I haven't been able to get eclipse to recognize variable set in this manner.

I should note, that i am using re-packaged version of eclipse cdt.

Thanks for your help!

[image]